# Error in writing a class

Tags: python, class

I am running through a tutorial online at http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson08/ and I believe I understand how classes work in python, at least to some degree but when I run this code:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    description = "This shape has not been described yet"
    author = "Nobody has claimed to make this shape yet"
    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y
    def describe(self,text):
        self.description = text
    def authorName(self,text):
        self.author = text
    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
    self.y = self.y * scale
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:/python/Shape.py", line 1, in -toplevel-
    class Shape:
  File "Y:/python/Shape.py", line 17, in Shape
    self.y = self.y * scale
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Any Help would be great

Thanks

Richard

Comment: I'm no python expert (so I can't help), but I would recommend using the code block in the editor for your code, especially since Python relies on indentation.  Then people will be able to see exactly what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @Richie: ahh, nice :)  wish I could have done that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to indent the last line.

```
def scaleSize(self,scale): 
    self.x = self.x * scale 
self.y = self.y * scale
```

Should be

```
def scaleSize(self,scale): 
    self.x = self.x * scale 
    self.y = self.y * scale
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. This is a the first time I used stackoverflow. I can already see that this going to be a great community to get involved in. Thanks all.

Comment: @Richard, if this answer has answered your question, its suggested you click the arrow next to the answer box. This ensures anyone else who comes to the site with the identical problem and quickly identify which one works.

Answer (score 3):

The last part of your code is wrong,

```
def scaleSize(self,scale):
    self.x = self.x * scale
self.y = self.y * scale
```

Notice the indentation, which is important in Python. By what you have now, means `self.y = self.y * scale` is not *inside* the `scaleSize` method and the keyword `self` is undefined for your `Shape` class.

What you need to do is properly indent,

```
def scaleSize(self,scale):
    self.x = self.x * scale
    self.y = self.y * scale
```

Answer (score 1):

The indicated line has the wrong indent level, so it's not in the `scaleSize()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to align line 17 with line 16

You have:

```
def scaleSize(self,scale):
    self.x = self.x * scale
self.y = self.y * scale
```

Must be:

```
def scaleSize(self,scale):
    self.x = self.x * scale
    self.y = self.y * scale
```

That's how python knows they belong to the same method.